# Mac won't appear on AirDrop until I open the "Air Drop" folder in finder

Tags: ios, finder, macos, airdrop

I've run into a rather minor, albeit annoying issue with Airdrop where my Mac Mini won't appear on the AirDrop section of the share sheet on my iPhone until I open the "AirDrop" folder in Finder on my Mac. As soon as I open it, my Mac shows up and I can share the file.

How can I have my Mac always show up in the share sheet without me having to open finder?